# How do I get $a_{n-1} = -a_{n}(d_{1}z_{1} + d_{2}z_{2} + \cdots + d_{r}z_{r})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if the polynomial $p(z) = a_{z}z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0$ is written in factored form as $p(z) = a_{n}(z-z_1)^{d_1}(z-z_2)^{d_2}\cdots (z-z_r)^{d_r}$, then

$a_{n-1} = -a_{n}(d_{1}z_{1} + d_{2}z_{2} + \cdots + d_{r}z_{r})$.

Initially, I was thinking that I could do some sort of partial fraction decomposition with the following:

$\frac {a_{z}z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0}{a_{n}(z-z_1)^{d_1}(z-z_2)^{d_2}\cdots (z-z_r)^{d_r}}=1$

but, I don't really know how to proceed without proceeding with brute force to multiply out the factored form.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  The coefficient $a_{n-1}=-a_ne_1(\underbrace{z_1,\dots,z_1}_{d_1-times},\dots,\underbrace{z_r,\dots,z_r}_{d_r -times})$, where $e_1$ is the [first elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

Note that $e_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1+\dots+x_n$.

*The fundamental theorem of elementary symmetric polynomials* implies this result.